# Reading a file with ISO-8859 encoding

Tags: ruby

According to Mac OSX, I have a file with ISO-8859 encoding:

```
$ file filename.txt
filename.txt: ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators
```

I try to read it with that encoding:

```
> filename = "/Users/myuser/Downloads/filename.txt"
> content = File.read(filename, encoding: "ISO-8859")          
> content.encoding
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

It doesn't work. And consequently:

```
 > content.split("\n")
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Why doesn't it read the file as ISO-8859?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code, Ruby emits the following warning when reading the file:

> warning: Unsupported encoding ISO-8859 ignored

This is because there is not only one [ISO 8859 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) but actually quite a bunch of variants. You need to specify the correct one explicitly, e.g

```
content = File.read(filename, encoding: "ISO-8859-1")
# or equivalently
content = File.read(filename, encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
```

When dealing with text files produced in Windows machines (which is hinted by the CRLF line endings), you might want to use `Encoding:::Windows_1252` (resp. `"Windows-1252"`) instead. This is [a superset of ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and used to be the default encoding used by many Windows programs and the system itself.

Comment: ISO/IEC 8859-1 was mostly superseded by ISO/IEC 8859-15. ISO/IEC 8859-15 has the `€` euro sign where ISO/IEC 8859-1 has the `¤` currency sign. Nobody uses the currency sign, while it is far more likely that someone would be using the euro sign. Therefore, I believe, ISO/IEC 8859-15 is far more likely than ISO/IEC 8859-1.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Encoding::ISO_8859_1` instead.

Comment: While this answer may indeed solve the problem it would be more helpful if you also explain why this solves the issue and where the problem with the original approach was.